# WinRM cannot process the request

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

"Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090304 occurred while using Negotiate authentication: An unknown security error occurred."

I'm attempting to run scripts remotely to non-domain servers and the clients are also not part of a domain since our environment is based on MicroFocus eDirectory.

I've configured/tried the following on both client AND server:

```
winrm quickconfig
WinRM set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="*"}
Set-item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value *
```

And again, none of the machines are part of a domain but I assumed it would work with trustedhosts.

Code attempting to authenticate looks like this:

```
[xml]$windows=(Get-Content P:\script\windows.xml)

$windows.servers.host | ForEach-Object {

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $_.pass -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "$_.name+$_.user",$password

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.name -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture}
}
```

Comment: Is ps remoting enabled on the target machine? `enable-remoting`

Comment: It is, the first line "winrm quickconfig" includes enabling the PSremoting, I also tried enabling it separatly after it didn't work but no dice yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the formatting of the username.  "$*.name+$*.user" will evaluate to a string with a + in the middle of it since the quotes are wrapped around both elements.  correct way to write it would be `"$($_.name)$($_.user)"` or more likely if the source file does not place a trailing '\' on the name field
 `"$($_.name)\$($_.user)"`

Comment: This is not the problem since the $_.user variable starts with a \ so it is as intended I'm afraid.

Comment: the `+` in the middle of the string is still evaluating as a character and not an operator, if the slash is in the input `"$($_.name)$($_.user)"` or `($_.name + $_.user)` would be the correct formatting.  your currently generating a string that looks like "Name+\User"

Comment: Ah now I see what you're getting at! You're absolutely correct and it seems your first suggestion `"$($_.name)$($_.user)"` works much better but the ($_.name + $_.user) can't be used I think since it wants a string.  
Thank you very much, the entire connection now works as intended!